# get_user_meta returning old data

Tags: user-meta

I have a page template that creates a user directory listing for certain of my site users.

I have no caching plugin and I get the same result from local development server, remote development server and live server.

The directory page does not reflect any changes made to the user profile it is as though it is being cached somewhere. It make no difference whether I update the profile using the native Wordpress admin page or using Gravity Forms User Registration update form.

I have tried
`$bio = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', true );`
and also 
`$all_user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
$bio = $all_user_data->description;`

Both return old data not the updated data from the profile.

Comment: please clear your history (catch memory)

Comment: As I said above I don't have any caching enabled.

Comment: I tried running clean_user_cache($user_id). No luck.